# Удаление папок Windows Kits

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, windows-10, visual-studio-2017

Столкнулся с интересным вопросом, причем ничего явно отвечающего на него в интернете не нашел.
Собственно, есть папка *Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits/10/Include* и *Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib*. Обе папки содержат несколько других, причем, судя по названию, это разные версии(*10.0.1240.0, 10.0.10586.0*). Самая актуальная похоже *10.0.17763.0*. Именно к ней меня ссылает Visual Studio (пишу на c++), когда я узнаю пути расположения заголовков стандартной библиотеки(например, iostream).
Я посчитал, что на данный момент активно используется только *"актуальная"* папка с заголовками, а остальные просто занимают память(прямо как windows.old, ожидающая отката). Проще говоря - можно ли удалять эти папки и, если можно, какие последствия это может понести.

Вот все их названия:
*10.0.10240.0

10.0.10586.0

10.0.14393.0

10.0.15063.0

10.0.16299.0

10.0.17134.0

10.0.17763.0 (последняя)*
Занимают много место, поэтому будет не лишним от них избавится.

Comment: Снимите галочки с ненужных SDK в установщике Visual Studio

Comment: @VTT, Действительно, зашел в установщик увидел на этих пакетах галочки. Уже удаляются... Так просто, спасибо Вам больше!

Comment: windows.old кстати тоже можно удалить воспользовавшись очисткой диска

Comment: @VTT, да, постоянно проверяю на наличие этой папки после обновления и удаляю. И еще, как я могу сразу избавится от всех ненужных таких же папок. Галочки то я убрал, правда ничего не изменилось, он наоброт скачал что еще, я полез и сам поудалял(ориентированно он писал что все эти папки мне обходились в 14 Гб, но удалил я на 7-8 Гб).

Comment: Все эти пакеты можно было удалить в "Установке и удалении приложений Windows". Это мне помогло.